# Functions in a for Loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I have some code I am trying to get to iterate over some images in a slider effect. However when I try to call the function from within my for loop it doesn't work. But if I have the call to `animateImage` function outside of the loop it works fine, but only runs once. How can I get this to run successfully fade in, fade out - loop again- fade in fade out?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function animateImage() {
    $('#mainImage').fadeOut( 5000, function() {
      $(this).fadeIn(5000);
    });

    for (var i = 0, limit = 7; i < limit; i++) {
      animateImage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share how you call the function in your for loop?

Comment: There seems to be some curly braces missing, particularly the one to end the animateImage function

Comment: @Mischa Sure you can, function definitions can be nested.

Comment: You need to match your braces. I'd recommend formatting your code so that it's more obvious when you miss matching braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that animate was getting called before the previous finished.

This will do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/q9ssn/2

Note: I set the time to 1 second for testing purposes so you can see it quicker.

```
function animateImage(times) {
    times = (times | 1);
    var i = 1;
    var fadeInAndOut = function() {
        $('#mainImage').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(1000, function () {
                if (i++ < times) {
                    fadeInAndOut();
                }
            });
        });
    };
    fadeInAndOut();
}
animateImage(7);
```

Comment: Okay cool, can I ask why you have called fadeInAndOut(); twice?

Comment: The first time (the one at the bottom) just gets it started initially.. then the function calls itself as many times as necessary.

Comment: I also noticed it ran 8 times instead of 7, I updated it by initializing `i` to `1`. I also put `times = (times | 1)` at the top.. all this does is make it so that if you call `animateImage()` without a parameter it will be given a default value of `1`

Comment: Great thanks for that solution. Works well for what I needed. Can I also just ask what the (times | 1) is doing. I know you explained there but I still dont get it.. lol

Comment: think of it as `use times if times is initialized to a truthy value, otherwise use 1`

Comment: So if the value of times is set to true use it OR use 1?

Comment: not just true, a truthy value (7 is an example of a truthy value). Here is a page that talks about truthy/falsy values: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for an animation to finish to tell jQuery to animate again, so you need to use some asynchronous pattern, like this one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function animateImage(cb) {
      $('#mainImage').fadeOut( 5000, function() {
          $(this).fadeIn(5000, cb);
      });
  }

  var i = 0, limit = 7;
  function maybeAnimateImage() {
    if (++i < limit)
      animateImage(maybeAnimateImage);
  }
  maybeAnimateImage();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are having syntax errors of braces and brackets ...

The correct code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animateImage() {
        $('#mainImage').fadeOut( 5000, function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(5000);
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0, limit = 7; i < limit; i++) {
        animateImage();
    }
});
```

Best of luck

Comment: @matehat can predefined event driven function like $('#mainImage').fadeout(.. can work inside a user defined function animateImage() ?? because the former is called by element driven action .. you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: There's no difference between user-defined or event-driven (or whatever term to describe) functions in javascript. The only things that matters are: 1. what scope of variable they capture and 2. where they are visible. Functions defined in another function are only visible and usable there, unless they're returned or bound to variables defined outside that function, in which case they're visible where those variables are. I would suggest reading that book to familiarise with js principles (they're pretty simple actually): http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593272821.do